# What is the proper statistical test when comparing a single output from multiple paired conditions with missing data?

Tags: statistical-significance

A simple example may illustrate this most clearly:

```
Length:  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
Sample 1: #    #    #   nan   #
Sample 2: #   nan   #   nan   #
Sample 3: #    #    #    #   nan
Sample 4: #    #   nan   #   nan
```

The measurement is taken for different lengths for each sample, but not all samples are measured at every length. "#" corresponds to a measured number and for "nan" no measurement was taken at that length.  All samples are measured at the first length (reference length)

**What is the proper statistical test to see if the measurements at subsequent lengths are significantly different from the first length?**